# Search all columns in a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want a procedure that will search all columns for non keyboard ascii characters (Dec 16 to Dec 31 or DLE to US) and update the column by replacing them with a space `' '` or nothing `''`.

I have a `SELECT` statement that is finding the rows I need to update, but I have to manually change all columns myself.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name REGEXP '[[.DLE.]-[.US.]]'
```

Here's the `UPDATE` script for modifying the column values

```
UPDATE table
SET
column = replace(column,char(16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31), '')
```

I want those two to be fused together to a single function or stored procedure but I don't know how, since I'm just starting to learn MySQL.

Comment: are you wanting to just run this `UPDATE` on a single table, or all tables in a database?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want that to run on a single table only but if possible Yes, I'd love to run it across all tables in the database.

Comment: Do mention if the answer posted isn't suitable, I think I correctly understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

Between using `REGEXP` and `CURSOR`s to loop through each table and column, these examples are not going to be lightning fast. The speed will obviously vary depending on your environment and I suggest testing them out on development before production

**One column in one table**

To search a single column on a single table, you basically had the `UPDATE` as you needed it.

```
UPDATE t1
SET
column_name = replace(column_name, 
  char(16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31), '')
WHERE column_name REGEXP '[[.DLE.]-[.US.]]'
```

**All columns in one table**

To do all columns in a table, you need to identify the table, then loop through the columns [using a cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE table_regexp_replace(in_table VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE search_column VARCHAR(64);

  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
      WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = in_table ORDER BY `ORDINAL_POSITION` ;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    -- Process the next column
    FETCH cur1 INTO search_column;

    -- If we're done, stop the loop
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    -- Replace everything in this column matching the regexp
    SET @new_query := CONCAT ('UPDATE ', in_table, 
        ' SET `', search_column, '` = replace(', search_column, 
          ', char(16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31), \'\')
        WHERE ', search_column, ' REGEXP \'[[.DLE.]-[.US.]]\'') ;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @new_query;
    EXECUTE stmt ;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then usage

```
CALL table_regexp_replace('my_table');
```

**How it works**

Looks convoluted, it's actually pretty straight forward.

1. We create a procedure with one parameter `in_table` which is used to specify the table to work with.
2. Setup a cursor that pulls the column names from the `information_schema` table, in their correct order
3. Loop through each of those columns, executing the manually created `UPDATE` statement against each one.

You'll notice anywhere in the `UPDATE` query that required quotes, they've had to be escaped using `\`.

```
\'[[.DLE.]-[.US.]]\'
```

**All columns in all tables**

You could then use this procedure in a loop through all tables, using a similar method to above. Below is how you'd pull all the table names from `information_schema`:

SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
  WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'your_database_name';

Comment: Can I use this code (your code) `UPDATE t1
SET
column_name = replace(column_name, 
  char(16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31), '')
WHERE column_name REGEXP '[[.DLE.]-[.US.]]'` to loop over colums or just change the column name from single column to many columns

Comment: Hi,Ho can i create this procedure. Every time I try to create it it says `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; chec the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMETE $$ CREATE PROCEDURE table_regexp_replace(in_table VAR' at line 1`

Comment: @Patrick You have spelt `DELIMITER` wrong, be sure you copy / paste it  correctly. The original comment you posted, that query is just for searching a single column in a table. Replace `t1` with your table name, and `column_name` with the name of the column.